# how to add and compare date time in posgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a below table

[image]

I want to write a query where the date is 29-10-2020 and time is greater than or equal  12PM . How I can compare this type of(AM/PM) time?

Comment: `WHERE s_date = '2020-10-29' AND s_start_time > '12:00:00'`? You should tell us the data types of the columns.

Comment: The way the value IS DISPLAYED in your (unknown to us) client does not allow us to determine exactly how the value IS STORED.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe datatype of the column is varchar. shall i change this dtatype for this?

Comment: Never store DATE, TIMESTAMP or TIME values in a `varchar` column. That is a really bad idea.

Comment: yes, as suggested changed datatypes working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The way it is, you could query thusly:

```
WHERE to_date(s_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY') = '2020-10-29'
  AND to_timestamp(s_start_time, 'HH:MM AM')::time > '12:00:00'
```

Things would be much simpler if you used the `date` and `time without time zone` data types for the two columns.